# Update table but shows errors in another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently maintaining an old system in my company. I want to update a table but it's giving errors in another table. Here is my query :

```
USE [Corporate]
GO

ALTER TABLE transfer_detail NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Transfer_Detail]
   SET [Satuan] = 'DUS'
 WHERE  [Satuan] = 'CRT'
GO

ALTER TABLE transfer_detail CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
GO
```

But the errors says :

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Transfer_Out', table 'Corporate.dbo.Saldo_Gudang'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I've trying to figure out this problem with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any trigger on table '[dbo].[Transfer_Detail]'?

Comment: Hi @Kumar, Yes, it has trigger and I've disable it for temporary. Can you add a post so I can accept the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is any trigger exists on the table `'[dbo].[Transfer_Detail]'`?